# Why am I unable to ascend as Astarion?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I've just defeated Cazador, but am missing the dialogue option to ascend in his place. All I can do is stab him. What did I miss and is there any way to fix this other than reloading back?

[image]

Comment: Is Astarion with you?

Comment: Cazador wants you to activate Windows first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the scroll from the skull in the side-room, just before the ascension chamber.